# ASP.NET C# eCommerce Create new page dynamically when user post their item

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

So I am creating a website something like ebay where user can post their own stuff on our website.
What I want to ask is, I want to make sure that everytime the user post their item on our website, a new link/page will be generated for that page. Same thing as well as when they register, a new page/link containing their member information will be created

Is that common way of how people do it?
I was thinking create a new page dynamically every time the user post stuff, but wouldnt it be lots of pages in our system later in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: As per my understanding you want a separate view for every product . In that case use a shared view as template and load data into it

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new page every time is not a good idea.

You can use the Routing concept in MVC to achieve this. This is easy to implement. For every product uploaded by your customer should have a title so you can create a SLUG of that title and based on that slug you can create a Route in RouteConfig.cs

Now when and end user will hit that URL extract that slug from URL and check the same in you database, and display the information to the user.

Try something like this. you can find tons of article on web about routing.

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Product",
"Product/{Id}/{name}/{*src}",
new { src = @"(.*?)\.(html|htm|aspx|asp)" },
new { controller = "Product", action = "SpecialDetails" },
namespaces: new[] { "TestCart.Controllers" }
);
```

Thanks
Hope this helps!

Comment: you have type "now", but I think you like to say "not"

Comment: Thanks for the reply
Does this concept can be applied to ASP Web Form? (not MVC)

Comment: Yes. there are many URL rewriting modules on internet. You can use them to accomplish your task. Concept is same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use a database to save users input and keep a master page having dynamic fields which will be filled at the time of opening the specific product. It's easier, faster and efficient.

In plain asp have `<%= variable name %>` inside html fields to show the dynamic content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there a name for this concept?
 I am trying to search more materials

Comment: Theres no such specific name for that though like Inheritance or something. Its just dynamic sites, I'll add a comment if I find a one. And you're welcome